# Mostrar Rutas Absolutas

Tags: php, html

Estoy buscando la manera de mostrar la ruta completa de la página dentro de un menú que tengo, pero al entrar a cada una de las opciones en el navegador solo muestra la página principal. Por ejemplo me gustaría que se vea "https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters" y no "es.stackoverflow.com" Estoy usando Chrome como navegador principal.

Tengo mi código de la siguiente manera:

```
                 <li class="treeview">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i><span>Información</span> <!-- OPCION DE TIPO DE VISTA -->
                        <span class="pull-right-container">
                            <small class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></small>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                   <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
                        <?php
                            if($ID_PERFIL == 0 || $ID_PERFIL == 1 || $ID_PERFIL == 3)
                        { ?>
                                <li class="treeview">
                                    <a href="#"> <!-- TERCER BOTON OPCION -->
                                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i><span>Emisores</span>
                                        <span class="pull-right-container">
                                            <small class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></small>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                        <li class="active"><a href="emisores.php" id="Padding"><i class="fa fa-handshake-o"></i> Emisores</a></li>
                                        <li class="active"><a href="emisorcontacto.php" id="Padding"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i> Contactos</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                        <?php }
                        ?>
                  </ul>
                </li>
```

Gracias

Comment: Qué muestre dónde? Tenés escritos unos `href'"emisores.php"`, si los querés "absolutos", escribilos absolutos.

Comment: @azeós tal cual, a menos que ese código que muestras sea el que genera después PHP, aunque lo dudo mucho.

Comment: Gracias, que lo muestre en la barra de direcciones dentro del navegador. Al hacer click en ella muestra la ruta completa, pero si das un click fuera vuelve a mostrar solo la dirección de la página principal. No estoy seguro si es por un complemento de Chrome, pero estoy buscando muestre siempre la ruta completa.

Comment: Cualquier página que abra me muestra por ejemplo: es.stackoverflow.com pero si doy click a la  barra de direciones muestra: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/403613/mostrar-rutas-absolutas?noredirect=1#comment722549_403613. Hay manera a nivel código forzar que el navegador muestre la ruta completa?

Comment: Entiendo que no, eso es una decisión de Chrome. Firefox si muestra el "scheme".

Comment: Eso depende de la **configuración del navegador**, no tiene nada que ver con el código, en el cual lo que debes asegurar es que la URL sea correcta, nada más.